# Как сравнить группу элементов в массиве в с++?

Tags: c++, массивы, сравнение

Дан целочисленный массив а1, а2,…, аn, среди элементов которого могут быть равные. Из каждой группы равных между собой элементов нужно оставить только один, выбросив все остальные. Освободившийся хвост массива заполнить нулями.
Я тут начал, но не понимаю как продолжить.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
setlocale(0, "");
int y;

std::cout << "Введите кол - во переменных в массиве: ";
std::cin >> y;

int* a = new int[y];
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
    std::cin >> a[i];
    }
 }
```

Comment: А стандартными алгоритмами С++ можно пользоваться? `sort`, `unique`?

Comment: да, конечно. Главное решить

Comment: Сортируете массив. Заводите переменную - счетчик смещения (или индекс последнего элемента в итоговом массиве). Проходите по массиву если элемент не равен предыдущему - копируете по текущему индексу минус смещение. А если равен - не копируете, а увеличиваете счетчик смещения. Получившуюся разницу заполняете нулями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз можно пользоваться стандартными алгоритмами...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cout << "Введите кол - во переменных в массиве: ";
    cin >> n;

    int* a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    sort(a,a+n);
    int * e = unique(a,a+n);
    while(e != a+n) *e++ = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: По мне, задача не предусматривает сортировку

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В условии об этом ничего не сказано. Никакого запрета нет.